# JS regexp to match words, include words surrounded by spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

Expression:

```
/(^|[^ \/?$])\b(foo)\b/g
```

Test string:

```
foo             - need this 1
<div>foo</div>  - need this 2
 foo            - need this 3

Foo             - dont need this
foobar          - dont need this
/foo/           - dont need this
```

Substitution:

```
$1bar
```

Need help to improve this regexp to work with ex# 3. [See demo](https://regex101.com/r/lR0eE2/2)

Comment: Try [`(^|[^\/])\bfoo\b`](https://regex101.com/r/dF8kZ0/1). Or even `(^|[^\/])\bfoo\b(?!\/)`. Will you be using the regex in both JS and R? In R, you will need to use `perl=T` option with `gsub` if you plan to use a regex with lookarounds.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `(^|[^\/])\b(foo)\b` and change your substition to `$2bar`